# Insert Data from TVP to table not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductInventory](
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Stock] [int] NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ImpID] [int] NOT NULL,
   ...........................
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sources](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](225) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](225) NOT NULL
)
```

Here is my simple TPV,

```
CREATE TYPE DictionaryType AS TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
    ,[Key] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Now I am going to update the ProductInventory,

What I need is to update ProductInventory using DictionaryType TVP. Here @Inventory is DictionaryType TVP,

```
UPDATE  ProductInventory
    SET [Stock] = InvType.[Value]
FROM    @Inventory InvType
        INNER JOIN Products P ON (P.ImpID = InvType.ID)
        INNER JOIN [Sources] S ON (S.Code = InvType.[Key])
        INNER JOIN ProductInventory PIn ON (PIn.ProductID = P.ID AND PIn.SourceID = S.ID)
WHERE   PIn.ProductID IS NULL;
```

Every thing is fine but ProductInventory can also contain SourceID = -1 means `any-source`. Now my TVP can contain Key(SourceID) = -1. How to update the above SQL to support this feature?

Comment: Do you mean, you simply want to add records where `SourceID = -1` & no  relation with joins data?

Comment: @PranavSingh, Yes there is no relation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
UPDATE  ProductInventory
    SET [Stock] = InvType.[Value]
FROM    @Inventory InvType
        INNER JOIN Products P ON (P.ImpID = InvType.ID)
        INNER JOIN [Sources] S ON (S.Code = InvType.[Key])
        INNER JOIN ProductInventory PIn 
           ON (PIn.ProductID = P.ID AND PIn.SourceID = S.ID) 
                OR PIn.SourceID=-1  --<<<<CHANGE
WHERE   PIn.ProductID IS NULL;
```

Comment: any chance you tested this before answering?